# Web Development: how to access a variable from an embedded c code to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, c, variables

I'm new to web development and I'm using AppWebServer to [AppWeb](http://appwebserver.org/products/appweb/embedded-web-server.html) to host my website.
AppWeb provides ESP (Embedded Server Pages) that is used to create web applications. You may embed a C code.

Now my problem is. I have a javascript code and a C Code, I need to access a variable from the C code and use it in javascript, the question is how do I do that?

I am thinking that even if I declare the variable as global, I wont still be able to access.

Comment: Is the javascript executed in the client or on the server?

Comment: @KlasLindback in the server.

Comment: Maybe start by reading the documentation? Section about modules seems promising: http://appwebserver.org/products/appweb/doc-4/guide/appweb/programmers/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hidden input type using HTML and insert the variable you want with something like 
`<input type="hidden" id="something" value <%=function in c that returns your variable%>" />`
and then access it with your JavaScript using `getElementById("something")`